# Retrieve all images files (RAW) from the entire PODIO space

Tags: podio

Our organistation has to  move out of PODIO and want to save alle the image files from the entire PODIO space. Not just one app, also from STATUS and all workspaces.

Has anyone a ready made script for it? PLS help!
Regards Reinhard